# Passing a function as an argument in a separate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that i want to pass as a parameter

```
function myFun(){

}

function myFunParam(myFun){

}
```

is above code correct ? How do I call the function `myFun` within `myFunParam` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFun(){
}

function myFunParam(myFun){
    if ($.isFunction(myFun)){         
        //Added example of passing arguments to myFun
        myFun.apply(this, ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']);
    }
}
```

You can also pass anonymous functions,

```
myFunParam(function(){
    alert('anonymous function');
});
```

Comment: Added example of passing arguments to myFun, must be reviewed though

Answer (score 3):

```
function myFun(){
   alert('test');
}

function myFunParam(myFun){
   if (typeof myFun === "function")
      myFun(); // alerts "test"
}
```

If your function, needs an argument, you would do:

```
function myFun(myarg){
   alert(myarg);
}

function myFunParam(myFun){
   if (typeof myFun === "function")
      myFun('foo'); // alerts "foo"
}
```

Or you can also pass **any number of arguments** using [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object (actually an array-like object).

Comment: what if the function myFun has a parameter also ?

Comment: @user701254: That's already mentioned in my answer, argument also means parameter here :) See second example.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, but I would certainly rename the parameter to avoid confusion between the global myFun and the parameter:

```
function myFunParam(func) {
    func(); // call function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. You need to call this way:

```
function myFun(){
}

function myFunParam(myFun){
    // Other Statements
    myFun();
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

OR you can do like this also

```
var newFunction = function() {
alert("I am in newFunction");
}


function calleFunction(func) {
func();
}

calleFunction(newFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function outerFunction(innerFunction) {
    innerFunction(); // call inner function
}
```